# Clone and Build Pentaho Kettle

Tags: eclipse, pentaho, kettle

Sorry for basic question, but I have been trying for a while and cannot get anywhere with this.
Any one have experience clone the Pentaho-kettle project and import it into eclipse?
I follow the instruction from https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle.
I did the following

```
cd pentaho-kettle
ant clean-all resolve create-dot-classpath
```

Then I go into eclipse and Import Existing Project into workspace. Note that I am importing from the root folder. Should I include the option scan the nested projects? 
Even that, I went into almost all the module(core, engine, ui...) to run the same ant task. However, I still have a bunch of error within eclipse.
Some errors are : Cannot find Type java.lang.Object (which is really strange), and a bunch other not resolving.
Is there any other step I need to follow. If you have success cloning and building from the repo, please help me out here.

---

To update, this is what I got after following the instruction:
[image]

Comment: Why do you need to import the project into Eclipse ? Building kettle from command-line is far simpler!

Answer (score 0):

How to build Pentahos Kettle

Simple instructions are underneath.

Necessary tools

- eclipse http://www.eclipse.org
- ant https://ant.apache.org

First, execute to get latest master

```
git checkout https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle.git
```

then execute (to get stable release u need)

```
git checkout -b production origin/production
```

where *production* is one of names can be found (highlighted red)

[image]

u actually already may import this project into eclipse (File->Import). Better if u will assign to eclipse at least 2GB RAM (it is pretty big project). Make some changes in $ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini file:

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
```

Now after import is done, eclipse will look this way

[image]

Highlighted:

- red (default projects after import pentaho-kettle project)
- blue are projects i checked out (consider version as well) and add to pentaho-kettle project in build path (Some of class missing despite they have to be in classpath according ivy)
- green errors are bugs in eclipse. Those left after even I successfully build/run/execute kettle DI. Another errors are no good.

Open console (I assume ant already available on u machine and ant command already in your PATH)

```
cd pentaho-kettle
```

enter to each projects (highlighted red, except *pentaho-kettle* project) directories and execute

```
ant clean-all resolve create-dot-classpath
```

refresh projects in eclipse.

Note: do not execute in pentaho-kettle directory command

```
ant clean-all resolve create-dot-classpath
```

It will erase all libraries in subprojects and u will have to start from beginning.

You are done. Now start/debug kettle in eclipse  (item in Run Configuration *pentaho-kettle* will be available)

Some of projects on image highlighted blue, they are used in pentaho-kettle (I think they suppose to be precompiled as jar files in pentaho-kettle/lib but ivy script didn't download them and didn't add them to pentaho-kettle project classpath. Eclipse will report "*Some* of classes are missing". I just checked them out from github manually as separate project (respect version) and add them to pentaho-kettle project in build path options
[image]

This is it.

Comment: so is it ok for the pentaho-kettle project to have some red? Also, I followed your instruction and not running ant in root "pentaho-kettle", however, I think without that I will not have the pentaho-kettle.launch which need for the run configuration. How should I proceed from there?

Comment: run/debug will be available in there after project import into eclipse. I don't remember exactly but i think pentaho-kettle.launch is needed only if u want to make final zip package.

Comment: Hey, I noticed you have the "pentaho-kettle/plugins/market/src" in your src...I am checking the 6.1.0.1 branch and do not see that market folder. Do you have any idea?

Comment: After import,  i looked on error panel, it indicates missing classes in project. They suppose to be in jar files in lib directory (ivy suppose to download them and add to classpath) but for some reason they went missing, so i just looked for them on github in https://github.com/pentaho using usual search. Them i checked them out and add to project build path, respect version.