# Pentaho Kettle Build Failed While Compiling subfloor.xml

Tags: java, ivy, kettle

I was trying to compile pentaho-kettle using

```
ant dist
```

command as instructed on github repository https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle, when I came across some compile error:

```
compile.compile:
[javac] /home/dimasta/Documents/pentaho-kettle/core/build-res/subfloor.xml:1560: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 352 source files to /home/dimasta/Documents/pentaho-kettle/core/bin/classes
[javac] javac: invalid target release: 8
[javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[javac] use -help for a list of possible options

BUILD FAILED
/home/dimasta/Documents/pentaho-kettle/build.xml:123: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/dimasta/Documents/pentaho-kettle/build.xml:128: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/dimasta/Documents/pentaho-kettle/core/build-res/subfloor.xml:1560: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 21 seconds
```

How to solve this?

P.S. I'm new to pentaho-kettle so please explain it in the easiest way possible

Thanks.

Comment: check is it in there file:///home/dimasta/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.3/jackson-databind-2.3.3.pom

Comment: ivy refer to pom package, meanwhile u might have in local maven repository jar package

Comment: I get use to import pentaho-kettle into eclipse,  run ivy resolve and manually adjust Build Path of project (adding all jar in lib dir to build path). Reason is a little mess in project itself (some of  subprojects missing like libfont, swt, and some others subprojects) so still need to make hands dirty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954531/clone-and-build-pentaho-kettle

Comment: Hi @simar thank you for replying. I've already solved the problem. The problem that has been causing the build failed is a corrupted ivy2 cache, so it makes the ant thinks that the com.fasterxml.jackson.core dependencies have been resolved, but in reality it haven't. Now I have encountered a new problem and I'll update it in the question.

Comment: Just adjust jdk version to compile. Message clearly says it. There is compatibility between kettle version and jdk and used libraries. My preference is to checkout from stable branch, not master. I get use to build 5.2 version with jdk 1.7

Comment: @simar So that means I have to start all over again from the beginning? Or there is a way to just change the kettle version and adjust it with jdk I have without starting over?

Comment: To ensure only one way, try it. By default  target is 1.8, according to subfloor.xml in master branch https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/core/build-res/subfloor.xml. Ensure that u have jdk1.8 installed. Or check might be u have several jdk installed,  and ant choose older version of jdk (for example becouse JAVA_HOME variable points to jdk7)

Comment: @simar Oh I see, okay then better get started since the build really take some time. Thanks for your help :)